# Validate phone number in two different formats in Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, regex, mongoose, regex-group, regex-greedy

The phone number I need to validate needs to be at least 8 characters long and has two possible formats:

1. Must be at least 8 digits like "12345678"

   OR
2. Must have 2 or 3 digits before "-" and 6 or more digits after "-"

I need to solve this using a regex.

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work properly (1-22334455) gets accepted even though I want it to be rejected.

```js
number: {
    type: String,
    minLength: 8,
    validate: {
        validator: v => /\d{2,3}-\d{6,}/.test(v) || /\d{8,}/.test(v),
        message: "this is not a valid number"
    }
}
```

Another attempt (still doesn't quite do it):

```js
number: {
    type: String,
    minLength: 8,
    validate: {
        validator: v => /\d{2,3}-?\d{6,}/.test(v),
        message: "this is not a valid number"
    }
}
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: Have you tried `/^\d{2,3}-?\d{6,}$/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first solution, you have to add a constrain on the start and ending of the string, with `^` and `$`. That's why `1-22334455` get captured in both solution (in the 2nd solution, it is due to the `-?` section).

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^(?:\d{8,}|\d{2,3}-\d{6,})$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d{8,}` Match 8 or more digits
  - `|` or
  - `\d{2,3}-\d{6,}` Match 2-3 digits, `-` and 6 or more digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of strirng

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q08TKH/1)

Answer (score 1):

This was finally the answer: Thank you everyone for your feedback I really appreciate it. I missed the ^ at the beginning and $ at the end.

```
/^\d{2,3}-\d{6,}$/.test(v) || /^\d{8,}$/.test(v)
```